# SetInterval timing to change the cell color

Tags: javascript, html

**Issue** 
In the below code , say if i want to change the color of the cell 1 ,2 and 4 , then they change the color at different intervals. (say first 1 changes then 2 changes then 4 changes)

I want all of them (1,2 and 4) to change the color at the same time. 
That will look like all (1,2 and 4) are red , then all the 3 are blue again.

Here temp_array will have the cells that i have to change the color (say temp_array will have 1,2 and 4.

```
 function startChangingColor()
       {
            var temp;
            for(var i=0;i<temp_array.length;i++)
            {
                temp = temp_array[i];
                intervalid[i] = setInterval( createCB(temp) ,300);
            }
        }
        function createCB( val )
        {
           return function()
           {
              changeColor( val );
           };
        }

        var flag = true; 
        function changeColor (element)
        {
            if(flag==true)
            {
                 document.getElementById(CELL+element).className='redled';
                 flag=false;
            }
            else if (flag==false)
            {
                 document.getElementById(CELL+element).className='grayled';
                flag = true;
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't know if I'm reading this correctly but try this:

```
var
  cells = document.getElementsByTagName('td'),
  tempArray = [[0, 1, 3], [1, 2, 0]];

var createColorChanger = function (classNames, elements, elementSelection) {
  var currentIndex = 0;

  return function () {
    var className = classNames.shift(), i = 0, lim = elements.length;
    classNames.push(className);

    for (; i < lim; i += 1) {
      elements[i].className = elementSelection[currentIndex].indexOf(i) > -1 ? className : '';
    }

    currentIndex += 1;
    if (currentIndex >= elementSelection.length) {
      currentIndex = 0;
    }
  }
};

setInterval(createColorChanger(['grayled', 'redled'], cells, tempArray), 1000);
```

demo: http://jsfiddle.net/NZPTE/3/

​

Comment: I'm getting to know the cells that i have to change color during run time. (Say for first time it may be 0,1 and 3) , next it may be 2 and 3. Thats the reason i had it in an array and i used a for loop. Since its in a for loop , the first element of array gets created at one time , then the second element gets created at another time , thats why in my old code it changes. I will try your suggestion. Thanks

Comment: In the second jsfiddle one of the cells is red always ,it doesnt change the color

Comment: i.e. the 3rd cell changes color for the first time but not afterwards. It remains red. In my case that should go blank as the second set of elements is 1,2,0

Comment: Thanks for helping. In my case ,array values will change dynamically.  Say at the start Array will be (0,1,3) then after some time  array will be (1,2,4) . So what should happen is when the array is (0,1,3) only these 3 cells should change color.                              As soon as the new value (1,2,4) comes in (0 and 3 should go back to normal and 1,2,4 should change color.

Comment: @m4n07 changed it, have a look.

Answer (score 0):

*Since you've made more than one thread with the same question, I'll give you the same answer in this thread as I did in the last one.*

### Original answer

You're using the same flag, which leads to some sort of lock probably. The easiest solution for you is to just add another flag for the second version - but wouldn't it be much nicer with just one interval-function? If I were you I would probably also want to cache the elements instead of doing a lookup at each interval.

*Update;*

From a (removed) comment, you wanted to add elements dynamically to the same interval-function? I wrote a small plugin for you (yeah, slow and boring day at work). You can add elements and change CSS class names at runtime, or even stop the interval. Only tested in FireFox though, but it's standard JS and should work in most browsers...

**JavaScript file**

```
(function (window, document, undef) {

    var CB = {};

    if (typeof window.CB !== typeof undef) {
        return;
    }

    CB = function () {

        var elements   = [],
            classes    = ['first-round', 'second-round'],
            intervalId = 0;


        var flag     = 0;
        var switcher = function () {

            for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
                elements[i].className = classes[flag];
            }

            flag = 1 - flag;

        };


        return {

            setClasses: function (first, second) {

                classes = [first, second];

            },

            addElement: function (element) {

                elements.push(element);

            },

            init: function (element, firstClass, secondClass) {

                this.addElement(element);
                this.setClasses(firstClass, secondClass);

                return this;

            },

            start: function (interval) {

                intervalId = setInterval(switcher, interval);

            },

            stop: function () {

                clearInterval(intervalId);

            }

        }

    }();

    window.CB = CB;

})(window, document);
```

**HTML test page with usage example**

The test adds two additional elements at runtime (a timeout on 5 seconds), and changes the classes as well

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8" />

        <style>

            .container {
                width: 600px;
                margin: 50px auto;
            }
                .container > div {
                    width: 300px;
                    height: 50px;
                    float: left;
                }
                .container .clear {
                    clear: both;
                    float: none;
                    width: 0;
                    height: 0;
                }

            .first-class {
                background-color: red;
            }
            .second-class {
                background-color: blue;
            }

            .new-first-class {
                background-color: black;
            }
            .new-second-class {
                background-color: grey;
            }

        </style>

    </head>
    <body>

        <div class="container">
            <div id="Id1">

            </div>

            <div id="Id2">

            </div>
            <div class="clear"></div>
        </div>

        <div class="container">
            <div id="Id3">

            </div>
            <div id="Id4">

            </div>
            <div class="clear"></div>
        </div>

        <script src="CB.js"></script>
        <script>

            window.onload = function () {

                CB.init(document.getElementById('Id1'), 'first-class', 'second-class');
                CB.addElement(document.getElementById('Id2'));

                CB.start(120);

                setTimeout(function () {

                    CB.addElement(document.getElementById('Id3'));
                    CB.addElement(document.getElementById('Id4'));
                    CB.setClasses('new-first-class', 'new-second-class');

                }, 5000);

            };

        </script>

    </body>
</html>
```